# What is the difference between armor and rating?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

The description of every armor in the game says something like “97 Armor (Rating 54)”. The first part is clear, when I equip this armor, my (confusingly named) Armor Rating increases by that much. But what exactly does Rating mean?

[image: My character sheet]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Rating is the quality of the item (explained [here](http://www.swtor.com/gamemanual/how-to-play/items-and-equipment) under item rating)

> Equippable items have a rating indicating their general level of
>   quality. This number gives you a rough idea of how powerful the viewed
>   item is compared to other items you’re wearing. To raise the rating,
>   look for certain modification items that can increase these ratings,
>   and attach them to your equipment.

Comment: Interesting. Although it seems not all equippable items have a rating.