# Armour ratings and armour values

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between armor and rating?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/42357/what-is-the-difference-between-armor-and-rating)

Can anyone tell me why an item with 25 armour (rating 54) is better than 228 armour (rating 48)?

I've put in some mods to the trousers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a typo on tooltip for the item in question.

[Torhead](http://www.torhead.com/item/hpPwpBA) reports the item as having 307 armor, which matches what the "Stat Changes" box would lead one to expect ( 228 + 79 = 307)

Scuttlebutt says that this value will properly show up after you equip it, just not before.

Comment: I thought that the system was saying that you would gain 79 armor and 17 endurance on equip. Which would mean that those 20 armor mods aren't counted into the 25 armour on the greaves.  For those numbers to work out the greaves would have to have an actual armor value of 307.

Comment: @sarge_smith I did some investigation, and have updated my response.